# querying all users and their photos

Tags: sql, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm using parse as my backend. And just need some guidance querying it.
I want to show my users a list of all the other user's profiles. I have a user table and an images table with references to the associated user.

When I build my list should I query for a list of all users then submit a query for all photos associated with each user? Given N users. This would result in my client performing N+1 requests.

Is there a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like the best bet in my scenario is to use an array https://www.parse.com/docs/relations_guide#onetomany-arrays
In most cases you'll want to use a pointer. But if you know the number of relationships will be fewer than 100 an array allows you to perform the query at the same time you perform the first query. Awesome.